# concatenate dataLayer for impression tracking because of lazyloading

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to implement impression tracking on element visibility. I am following the guide of simo ahava

```
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/true-view-impressions-google-tag-manager/
```

Now I cannot replicate that example because it needs to fire all product once into the dataLayer but on my case i am doing lazy loading and have to push the product in batch into the dataLayer. Unfortunately by doing this every time we are pushing some element into the datalayer it will only take the last values of the event push on google tag manager so it is very possible that the product becomes visible but is no more available into the dataLayer.

Here is a more detailed explanation

Step 1 : We have a two push into the data layer for lazy loading purpose
 1a. first push as the first portion loads

```
dataLayer=[];

dataLayer.push({
 event: 'eec.impressionView',
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "impressions": [{
      "id": "9bdd2",
      "name": "Compton T-Shirt",
      "price": "44.00",
      "brand": "Compton",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "position": 0,
      "list": "shirts you may like"
    },
    {
      "id": "239b5",
      "name": "Pigzart T-Shirt",
      "price": "82.00",
      "brand": "Pigzart",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "position": 1,
      "list": "shirts you may like"
    }
    ],
  }
});
```

1b. second push due to lazy loading

```
dataLayer.push({
 event: 'eec.impressionView',
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "impressions": [
    {
      "id": "7w9e0",
      "name": "Masons T-Shirt",
      "price": "31.00",
      "brand": "Masons",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "position": 2,
      "list": "shirts you may like"
    },
    {
      "id": "57b9d",
      "name": "Kiosk T-Shirt",
      "price": "55.00",
      "brand": "Kiosk",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "position": 3,
      "list": "shirts you may like"
    }
    ],
  }
});
```

2 - Now let's say that the customer have an element visibility trigger that happen after the second dataLayer push on the product "Compton T-Shirt". It will not be able to know what are the information

So comes my questions , is there a way to concatenate the eec.impressionView events into a single one on the GTM side or is there a better way to handle this type of problem to be able to capture the impression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're encountering is known as "Recursive Merge", so the products you're pushing into the dataLayer merge in with the existing products in the internal data model, rather than being appended to it.

The easiest way to avoid the recursive merge is within your dataLayer push.

Instead of doing a full dataLayer push for your subsequent impressions

```js
dataLayer.push({
 event: 'eec.impressionView',
  "ecommerce": {
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "impressions": [
    {
      "id": "7w9e0",
      "name": "Masons T-Shirt",
      "price": "31.00",
      "brand": "Masons",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "position": 2,
      "list": "shirts you may like"
    },
    {
      "id": "57b9d",
      "name": "Kiosk T-Shirt",
      "price": "55.00",
      "brand": "Kiosk",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "position": 3,
      "list": "shirts you may like"
    }
    ],
  }
});
```

It works if you can use this for the subsequent dataLayer pushes.

```js
dataLayer.push(['ecommerce.impressions.push',
    {
      "id": "7w9e0",
      "name": "Masons T-Shirt",
      "price": "31.00",
      "brand": "Masons",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "position": 2,
      "list": "shirts you may like"
    },
    {
      "id": "57b9d",
      "name": "Kiosk T-Shirt",
      "price": "55.00",
      "brand": "Kiosk",
      "category": "T-Shirts",
      "position": 3,
      "list": "shirts you may like"
    }]);
```

This will prevent the second push from overwriting the existing values and because you're using visibility triggers there's no need for the repeated event, and everything else will be the same in the data model.

Alternatively you could use a custom HTML tag and fire that on each event to store the impressions in a separate JS object and reference that rather than the dataLayer in your Enhanced Ecommerce setup.

Comment: I'm attempting to use this, but using the Google Tag Assistant extension, it does not show further impressions using this. Are you aware of this being a problem with the GTA extension? I'm doing exactly as OP and yourself are doing. @James